# Organize figures in two columns and one above the other

Tags: graphics, captions, positioning

I would like to organize 3 figures as it's shown in the figure below:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question comes up every few days, use `\minipage`s.

Comment: Have a look at the `epslatex` manual, page 112: [ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex.pdf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? (The `[b]` position specifiers are needed to bottom-align subfigures b and c.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{report} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}
\caption{Caption A}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace*{5mm} % vertical whitespace
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}
\caption{Caption B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill        % horizontal whitespace
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.5\linewidth]{c}
\caption{Caption C}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption Bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The figures don't appear in the format that you show. They appear in a vertical line

Comment: @RaquelGomes - The screenshot is based *exactly* on the code I've posted. In your code, did you possibly insert one or more blank lines immediately before or after the `\hfill` instruction?

Comment: Yes, I add put a blank line. The problem is solved. Thanks