# 3 pictures in one with special layout

Tags: floats

Probably it is very easy but i don't know how to do it.
I want to put 3 images one on the left and the other 2 on the right. As for the 2 on the right i want them to be one above the other

thanks for the help

```
\begin{figure}[h!] 
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth, height = 10 cm]{Images/Ch3/hwinct3.jpg} 
\hspace{\fill} 
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth} 
\hspace{\fill} 
\begin{subfigure}{0.9\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=1.1\columnwidth]{Images/Ch3/plane1.pn‌​g} 
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth, height = 3 cm]{Images/Ch3/prova.png} 
\hspace{\fill} 
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure} 
\end{subfigure} 
\caption{Plane 1 measurements slots} 
\label{fig:pl1sl} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: See the answers to ["Side by Side figures"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323731/110998) and ["Organize figures in two columns and one above the other"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315823/110998).

Answer (score 2):

Putting images side by side is normally done using `minipage`, and on top of each other can be done by just seeing to that they occupy enough space to end up on different lines. It is not clear from the question if there should be individual captions or not. This solution should work in most cases. To get the spacing right for your pictures try changing the scaling factors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.89\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Picture A}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Picture B}
    \vspace*{\baselineskip} %% Space between small pictures
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}    
    \caption{Picture C}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \hbox to \linewidth{} %% Space between small pictures
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{example-image-c}    
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{One caption for all pictures.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

To have one common caption for all images and also let each one have its own caption the packets `subfloats`, `subfig` or `subcaption` can be used. Below is an example using `subcaption` where the `minipage` used earlier is replaced buy the `subfigure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.89\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Picture A}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.84\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Picture B}
    \vspace*{\baselineskip} %% Space between small pictures
    \includegraphics[width=0.84\linewidth]{example-image-c}    
    \caption{Picture C}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Common caption for all pictures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly.. Thanks very much.. As you could see I'm a newbie in Latex :)

Comment: While it is not possible to have like a caption for each figure but like a subcaption so that it is the same figure, e.g. 3.5 and each figure is 3.5a 3.5b and 3.5c ?

Comment: You can use `subfloats`, `subfig` or `subcaption`. See edit above for an example of `subcaption`.